# Dropdown menu disappears too quickly

Tags: html, css

I have a small piece of code written in HTML and CSS that creates a drop-down menu. When the button "E" is hovered a menu will popup. However the menu disappears too quickly for me to access it.
Is there a way to make the menu stay enough time for me to access it when the "E" button is hovered ?

Here is the code:

```css
#topbar {
  padding: 0px;
  background: black;
  height: 10%;
}

#e_button {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 100%;
}

#zul_menu {
  border: 1px black solid;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  //margin: 0;
  //padding: 0px;
  //overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

#e_button:hover~#zul_menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Up...</p>
</div>

<div id="topbar">
  <button id="e_button">E</button>
  <ul id="zul_menu">
    <li class="test"><a class="active" href="mainPage.php">Home</a></li>
    <li class="test"><a href="Cats.php"> Cats</a></li>
    <li class="test"><a href="Dogs.php">Dogs</a></li>
    <li class="test"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Down...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a wrapper div around button and dropdown, make it relative and add styles to its hover.

```css
#topbar {
  padding: 0px;
  background: black;
  height: 10%;
}

#e_button {
  width: 40px;
  height: 100%;
}

#zul_menu {
  border: 1px black solid;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  //margin: 0;
  //padding: 0px;
  //overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

#button_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

#button_wrapper:hover #zul_menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Up...</p>
</div>

<div id="topbar">
  <div id="button_wrapper">
    <button id="e_button">E</button>
    <ul id="zul_menu">
      <li class="test"><a class="active" href="mainPage.php">Home</a></li>
      <li class="test"><a href="Cats.php"> Cats</a></li>
      <li class="test"><a href="Dogs.php">Dogs</a></li>
      <li class="test"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Down...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add a note on what is the important change here. (no gap between toggle element and dropdown…)

Comment: Thx a lot Nandita for the elegant solution, worked like a charm :).

Comment: Thanks. Can you please accept it if it worked for you :)

Comment: @Orc2000 you must mark her answer as accepted if it worked for you.. so other people would get to know and not answer this.

Answer (score 1):

**hide with animation**
use `opacity` **instead of** `display: none/block`
You can use `opacity: 0;` to hide it and  `transition: opacity 0.5s 1s;` to animation ... `:hover` use `opacity: 1;` and `transition: opacity 0.5s;`

```css
#topbar {
  padding: 0px;
  background: black;
  height: 10%;
}

#e_button {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 100%;
}

#zul_menu {
  border: 1px black solid;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 1s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  //margin: 0;
  //padding: 0px;
  //overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

#e_button:hover~#zul_menu {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Up...</p>
</div>

<div id="topbar">
  <button id="e_button">E</button>
  <ul id="zul_menu">
    <li class="test"><a class="active" href="mainPage.php">Home</a></li>
    <li class="test"><a href="Cats.php"> Cats</a></li>
    <li class="test"><a href="Dogs.php">Dogs</a></li>
    <li class="test"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Down...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe it's worthy to note that the `display` property cannot be animated, just in case OP or anyone else wonders why you're using `opacity` instead of `display: none/block`

Comment: @Manoj : Thx man, maybe I will try you version later, for now though I am happy with Nandita's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a bit weird a dropdown with that margin from the trigger but if you like that you can achieve this by changing *display* property to *visibility* and a transition; also you'll need to add *#zul_menu:hover* behaviour (so when you're hovering over dropdown it will not close up):

```css
#topbar {
  padding: 0px;
  background: black;
  height: 10%;
}

#e_button {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 100%;
}

#zul_menu {
  border: 1px black solid;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 1s;
}

#e_button:hover~#zul_menu,
#zul_menu:hover {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Up...</p>
</div>

<div id="topbar">
  <button id="e_button">E</button>
  <ul id="zul_menu">
    <li class="test"><a class="active" href="mainPage.php">Home</a></li>
    <li class="test"><a href="Cats.php"> Cats</a></li>
    <li class="test"><a href="Dogs.php">Dogs</a></li>
    <li class="test"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Down...</p>
</div>
```